# IO/s and MB throughput for Various RAID Arrays

Tags: raid, storage, sas, benchmark

Are there any resources that have typical throughput and IOp/s for various RAID arrays under sequential and random patterns?

In my case I am more specifically interested in *at the moment*:

- 6 Disk Raid 10 Array with SAS 10k drives
- sqlio numbers

I know there  are a lot of variables here, how many operations are pending, the controller, caches etc... I have also seen the "formulas" for predicting RAID performance (which I kind of feel are perhaps a bit of malarkey) but some general targets of what good benchmarks are would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the calculators and find that they're in the ballpark for most cases. In many cases I've seen where people complain about the performance of their array, it's because the disks, controller, or processing architecture/system bus are out of alignment. Most modern servers come with PCIe and fast CPUs/FSBs (so they aren't an issue); but make sure you've got a good RAID controller. The MB's built-in controller is likely crap that might connect 6 drives, but wont push them too hard.

You're probably looking around 300 to 400 IOps write and close to double that read performance with those drives and a good RAID card (with sufficient WB cache). Throughput will be somewhat dependent on the areal density of the drives. Of course as you said, it's going to depend on your workload.